# keepalived track_script never runs

Tags: keepalived

Here's my keepalived.conf for the MASTER node:

```
vrrp_script chk_test {
        script "exit 1"
        interval 2
        weight 2
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    interface eth0
    state MASTER
    priority 200

    virtual_router_id 33
    unicast_src_ip 100.72.142.152
    unicast_peer {
        100.72.142.153
    }

    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass secret
    }

    track_script {
        chk_test
    }

    notify_master "/etc/keepalived/recover.sh MASTER"
    notify_backup "/etc/keepalived/recover.sh BACKUP"
    notify_fault "/etc/keepalived/recover.sh FAULT
}
```

The configuration for the second node is irrelevant to the question I have. From my understanding the script defined by `chk_test` should run every two seconds and if exit status is anything other than 0, the script defined under `notify_fault` should be called.

As you can tell my `chk_test` script just exists with 1, however it seems as though this script is never actually ran. Am I just missing something basic here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with the keepalived offered through the apt-get repos on Ubuntu 14.04. I downloaded, complied, and ran the latest version of keepalived with the same configuration files and everything ran correctly.